# CORS in Node.js and AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, restangular

I have a CORS problem with my app.

My stack is Node.js with [Express 4](http://expressjs.com/) and AngularJS using [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)

I already have tried a few things ([for example](https://gist.github.com/dirkk0/5967221)) but I keep getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/users. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

In the server side I have this headers:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST","PUT");
  next();
});
```

In the AngularJS part I am using this:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

And I am doing the post with Restangular like this:

```
var baseUsers = Restangular.all('users');
....
....
baseUsers.post(newUser).then(function(user){
console.log(user);
});
```

One more thing, in the Node.js server I am consoling the `req.method` and it says `OPTIONS`, I really don't know why.

Perhaps is something silly, hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change -

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
```

TO

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
```

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867775/cors-trouble-with-nodejs-and-angularjs)

[Source 2](http://www.wilsolutions.com.br/content/fix-request-header-field-content-type-not-allowed-access-control-allow-headers)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting same answer with a detailed code, Because i got some issues when i use the selected answer.

Just pull the code below after initialization of the `app` object

```
    app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST","PUT");
      next();
    });
```

I hope this will be little bit more helpful.