# Angular $http POST unable to send data to expressjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to post data from angular to express, however, eachtime I make the post request I get this error.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost/post/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11209s @ angular.js:11002g @ angular.js:10712(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15287m.$eval @ angular.js:16554m.$digest @ angular.js:16372m.$apply @ angular.js:16662(anonymous function) @ angular.js:24283m.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4670r.handle @ jquery.js:4338
controller.js:29
```

and the errorCallback response object is:

```
Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

I did some tweaking looking at other similar questions on SO, like adding header, content-type etc. But no luck there.

What seems to be the problem here.
Thanks

**Controller.js**

```
word.add = function(){
console.log(word.name );

    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'http://localhost/post/',
        data :word.name,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log("Successful");
    },function errorCallback(response){

        console.log(response);
        console.log("Unsuccessful");
    });     
};
```

Relevant code excerpt from **app.js**

```
 var routes = require('./routes/index');
    app.all('/*', function (request, response, next) {
       response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
  next();
});

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/post', routes);
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/post', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body.name);
    response.send('Reached post');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Edit:**
  Hi, I've already tried and added the content-type header in my response.
Still,It's the same error.

The same code works fine while I use this method to post.

```
$http.post('/post',{data: word.name}).success(function(response) {
       console.log("success");
      }).error(function(err){
         console.log("failure")
      });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS trouble with nodejs and AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867775/cors-trouble-with-nodejs-and-angularjs)

Comment: A preflight is fired. That means [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is in place. You can either make your client and server to be in same domain or add CORS headers.

Comment: @Phil I've looked into that question, and added the CORS, still facing the same error. I'm not sure if it's related to content-type header error.

Comment: Well, `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` makes me think your Express server isn't actually running (or at least, not running on port 80)

Comment: Hi, One weird behavior I encountered is, I'm able to post data successfully  while using this method. $http.post('/post',{data: word.name}).success(function(response) {
           console.log("success");
          }).error(function(err){
             console.log("failure")
          });

Comment: How did you solved it ? @nitte93user3232918

Comment: See the one in the edit part, I used that.

Answer (score 0):

expressjs listing at 9000 port by default. So, you post url should be http://localhost:9000/post/

Answer (score 0):

You must enable CORS on your server. Since the port is different on the same server it will treat it like a cross domain request.

http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html