# put operation in Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

For put request:

```
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
```

My update method look like this:

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Thing.findById(req.params.id, function (err, thing) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!thing) { return res.status(404).send('Not Found'); }
    var updated = _.merge(thing, req.body);
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.status(200).json(thing);
    });
  });
};
```

Making request:

```
$http.put('/api/things/'+ thing._id, updatedThingObject)
          .success(function(update){
            console.log("update", update)
          })
          .error(function(err){
            console.log("err", err)
          })
```

It gives connection error on passing the object while making the request in angular.

The error looks like this:

```
    PUT http://localhost:9000/api/things/56c8325b9a0ee7d00d266495
    net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11442sendReq @
```

If I take off the updated object, it makes the request just fine but ofcourse nothing gets updated in

that case. What might be wrong here,please?

I figured.

The reason for the functions not being called is that I have a function that is being called repetitively in Node .

```
var autoCreate = function(){
  console.log("THING CREATED AUTOMATICALLY")
  var randomNumb=0;
    clearTimeout(randomNumb);

     randomNumb = (Math.random()* (10-5) + 5).toFixed(0);
    console.log("random number", randomNumb)
   var randomThing =randomstring({
  length: randomNumb,
  numeric: false,
  letters: true,
  special: false
});
   console.log("ranfom thing", randomThing)

   Thing.create({
    name: randomThing,
    readByUser: false 
  }, function(err, thing) {
    console.log("THING IS", thing)
      //setTimeout(autoCreate, randomNumb * 1000);
    });





  }

  setTimeout(autoCreate, 10*1000);
```

Since this is running when post/put request is made, I get connection error. How do I handle this to be able to have this function running and be able to make put/post requests as well?

Comment: what's `updatedThingObject`?

Comment: I suspect `updatedThingObject` is causing the trouble as it might giving some errors making the connection go down and you are getting this error

Comment: No actually. Even if I pass exactly the same object without any updation, it still does not work

Comment: @Michelem: It returns the same error even when I pass the same object without any updation

Comment: First of all you need to check the Console Errors like CORS Policy errors .. developer Tools gives Hint for this kind of Clue Less thing Try it :-)

Comment: What's the error? Is it client or server side?

Comment: @N.V.Prasad:Thanks. but I can make get/post/delete request and problem is only with PUT request so CORS is probably not the issue here. update my question with error though :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259023/angular-http-post-unable-to-send-data-to-expressjs take a look at it .. it may gives You Clue

Comment: @N.V.Prasad: Could you please check the update? I figured the reason but not sure about the solution

Comment: You may need to Update Code in a Plunker :-) one more thing if your code is from nodejs You need to define function like export.autoCreate = function(){} like that .. but i need a plunker to fix the issue for sure it would be a simple one