# How To: Pass node.js mongodb result to angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

So I have a *MongoDB* that I query using *Node.js*.

The data is not being sent out using this function and I dont know what is wrong

```
var findIco = function(db, callback) {
   var cursor =db.collection('footIco').find();
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
     // console.log(err);
      if (doc != null) {
        console.log(doc); <------ DISPLAY THE DATA IN THE CONSOLE
      } else {
         callback();
      }
   });
}; 
app.get('/icons', function(req, res){
  //calling the function
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
   }

    findIco(db, function(icons) {
         res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
  console.log(icons);<--------------- IS UNDEFINED
        res.json(icons);
        db.close();
        return;
    });
  });
});
app.listen(8080);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use some form of Web Server to create an API that will return this data when a request is received at a certain resource. You can make the requests to your API using the `$http` service in your Angular app. The most popular choice for a Node web framework is [Express](http://expressjs.com), this wraps the Node Core [HTTP Module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html) and gives a robust [API](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html).

Other Popular Node.js Web Frameworks

- [Koa](http://koajs.com/)
- [Hapi.js](http://hapijs.com/)

These are just a couple of Node.js Web Frameworks, I also excluded any frameworks that are MVC based frameworks such as [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) and [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) since Angular already is providing that piece.

To get up and running quickly in Express, you can use [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) to scaffold out a basic Express API. Then just add a route for your function in your Node.js server.

**findIco**

```
var findIco = function(db, callback) { 
  db.collection('footIco').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) return callback(err, null);

    return callback(null, docs);
  }); 
}
```

**Node.js API**

```
app.get('/icons', function getIcons(req, res){
  //calling the function
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json(err);
   }

    findIco(db, function(err, icons) {
      if (err) 
        res.status(500).json(err);
      else {
        if (!icons)
          res.status(204).send();
        else
          res.json(icons);
      }
      db.close();
      return;
    });
  });
});
```

Angular `$http` call in `footIconCtrl`

```
app.controller('footIconCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.icons = [];

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://<serverAddress>:<serverPort>/icons'
  })
    .then(function(icons) {
      $scope.icons = icons.data;
    })
    .catch(function(errRes) {
      // Handle errRess
    });
});
```

Comment: And how do i define $http?

Comment: You don't define it, its provided in the core Angular module. The way you access it from your controller is inject it into your dependencies on your controller like so: `app.controller('footIconCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {});`

Comment: im getting this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/icons. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: i guess im missing a header or something

Comment: Your Angular app needs to be served by your express app or they need to be on the same domain, ie, they both need to be from `localhost`.

Comment: They are from the same domain

Comment: My web server runs on port 80 and my api on 8080. Both on localhost

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867775/cors-trouble-with-nodejs-and-angularjs), the question and answer code samples should help you work through this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103977/discussion-between-madeindreams-and-peteb).

Answer (score 1):

In your angular code, you will have a file like `getDocument.controller.js` with a function with an http call to your service. Something like this :

```
var getDocs = function(){
    var apis = http://localhost:9000/api/getDocs;
    httpRequest.get(apis).
    then(function(docs){
        // Your code to handle the response
    });
};
```

Now in your server side code, you can send the response as

```
CollectionName.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!docs) return res.send(401);
    res.json(docs);
});
```